# Increasing Performance of Sql query

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, oracle-sqldeveloper

Working to make this query faster for a long time, Coming up short.

DB Oracle: takes 57 seconds to load distinct of this query.

TOTAL_ROWS : 1866

All indexes are present for all the tables associated with this.

Need suggestion or code improvements for this, in case you want more information, please comment and do help.

```
  SELECT            
        SUM(COALESCE(ft8.dPercent, 1.00000000000000000000) 
           * COALESCE(ft7.dPercent, 1.00000000000000000000) 
           * COALESCE(ft6.dPercent, 1.00000000000000000000) 
           * COALESCE(ft5.dPercent, 1.00000000000000000000) 
           * COALESCE(ft4.dPercent, 1.00000000000000000000) 
           * COALESCE(ft3.dPercent, 1.00000000000000000000) 
           * COALESCE(ft2.dPercent, 1.00000000000000000000) 
           * ft1.dPercent * 100.00000000)
    FROM            
        ODS.YARDI_Property px
    INNER JOIN      
        ODS.YARDI_Fund_Tran ft1 ON px.hMy = ft1.hInvestor
                                AND ft1.iCategory = 0
                                AND ft1.dPercent <> 0
                                AND SYSDATE BETWEEN ft1.dtStart AND NVL(ft1.dtEnd, SYSDATE + 1)
 LEFT JOIN ODS.YARDI_PROPERTY P ON PX.HMY = P.HMY
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  
        ODS.YARDI_Fund_Tran ft2 ON ft1.hInvestment = ft2.hInvestor
                                AND ft1.hInvestment <> P.hMy 
                                AND ft2.iCategory = 0
                                AND ft2.dPercent <> 0
                                AND SYSDATE BETWEEN ft2.dtStart AND COALESCE(ft2.dtEnd, SYSDATE)

    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        ODS.YARDI_Fund_Tran ft3 ON ft2.hInvestment = ft3.hInvestor
                                AND ft2.hInvestment <> P.hMy
                                AND ft3.iCategory = 0
                                AND ft3.dPercent <> 0
                                AND SYSDATE BETWEEN ft3.dtStart AND COALESCE(ft3.dtEnd, SYSDATE)

    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        ODS.YARDI_Fund_Tran ft4 ON ft3.hInvestment = ft4.hInvestor
                                AND ft3.hInvestment <> P.hMy
                                AND ft4.iCategory = 0
                                AND ft4.dPercent <> 0
                                AND SYSDATE BETWEEN ft4.dtStart AND COALESCE(ft4.dtEnd, SYSDATE)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        ODS.YARDI_Fund_Tran ft5 ON ft4.hInvestment = ft5.hInvestor
                                AND ft4.hInvestment <> P.hMy
                                AND ft5.iCategory = 0
                                AND ft5.dPercent <> 0
                                AND SYSDATE BETWEEN ft5.dtStart AND COALESCE(ft5.dtEnd, SYSDATE)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        ODS.YARDI_Fund_Tran ft6 ON ft5.hInvestment <> P.hMy
                                AND ft5.hInvestment = ft6.hInvestor
                                AND ft6.iCategory = 0
                                AND ft6.dPercent <> 0
                                AND SYSDATE BETWEEN ft6.dtStart AND COALESCE(ft6.dtEnd,SYSDATE)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        ODS.YARDI_Fund_Tran ft7 ON ft6.hInvestment = ft7.hInvestor
                                AND ft6.hInvestment <> P.hMy 
                                AND ft7.iCategory = 0
                                AND ft7.dPercent <> 0
                                AND SYSDATE BETWEEN ft7.dtStart AND COALESCE(ft7.dtEnd, SYSDATE)
                                                       
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        ODS.YARDI_Fund_Tran ft8 ON ft7.hInvestment = ft8.hInvestor
                                AND ft7.hInvestment <> P.hMy 
                                AND ft8.iCategory = 0
                                AND ft8.dPercent <> 0
                                AND SYSDATE BETWEEN ft8.dtStart AND COALESCE(ft8.dtEnd, SYSDATE)
                                                     
    WHERE --P.HMY>4643
        trim(trailing ' ' from lower(px.sCode)) =   'rdrtinc'
     AND p.hMy IN (
        SELECT FT8.hInvestment  from    dual                        
        UNION   ALL
        SELECT FT7.hInvestment  FROM    dual
        UNION   ALL
        SELECT FT6.hInvestment  FROM    dual
        UNION   ALL
        SELECT FT5.hInvestment  FROM    dual
        UNION   ALL
        SELECT FT4.hInvestment  FROM    dual
        UNION   ALL
        SELECT FT3.hInvestment  FROM    dual
        UNION   ALL
        SELECT FT2.hInvestment  FROM    dual
        UNION   ALL
        SELECT FT1.hInvestment  FROM    dual
        )
    )
```

**EXPLAIN PLAN**

```
Plan hash value: 4073090911
 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                              | Name            | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                       |                 |     1 |    13 |   177K  (1)| 00:00:07 |
|   1 |  VIEW                                  |                 |     1 |    13 |   177K  (1)| 00:00:07 |
|   2 |   SORT AGGREGATE                       |                 |     1 |   235 |            |          |
|*  3 |    FILTER                              |                 |       |       |            |          |
|*  4 |     HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER              |                 | 11577 |  2656K|    39   (8)| 00:00:01 |
|*  5 |      TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL         | YARDI_FUND_TRAN |   123 |  3321 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  6 |      HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER             |                 |  8789 |  1785K|    34   (6)| 00:00:01 |
|*  7 |       TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL        | YARDI_FUND_TRAN |   123 |  3321 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  8 |       HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER            |                 |  6672 |  1179K|    30   (7)| 00:00:01 |
|*  9 |        TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL       | YARDI_FUND_TRAN |   123 |  3321 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 10 |        HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER           |                 |  5065 |   761K|    26   (8)| 00:00:01 |
|* 11 |         TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL      | YARDI_FUND_TRAN |   123 |  3321 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 12 |         HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER          |                 |  3845 |   476K|    22  (10)| 00:00:01 |
|* 13 |          TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL     | YARDI_FUND_TRAN |   123 |  3321 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 14 |          HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER         |                 |  2919 |   285K|    17   (6)| 00:00:01 |
|* 15 |           TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL    | YARDI_FUND_TRAN |   123 |  3321 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 16 |           HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER        |                 |  2216 |   157K|    13   (8)| 00:00:01 |
|* 17 |            TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL   | YARDI_FUND_TRAN |   123 |  3321 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 18 |            HASH JOIN                   |                 |  1143 | 52578 |     9  (12)| 00:00:01 |
|  19 |             JOIN FILTER CREATE         | :BF0000         |   263 |  4997 |     5  (20)| 00:00:01 |
|  20 |              NESTED LOOPS OUTER        |                 |   263 |  4997 |     5  (20)| 00:00:01 |
|* 21 |               TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL| YARDI_PROPERTY  |   263 |  3682 |     5  (20)| 00:00:01 |
|* 22 |               INDEX UNIQUE SCAN        | SYS_C0020229    |     1 |     5 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  23 |             JOIN FILTER USE            | :BF0000         |  2227 | 60129 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 24 |              TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL | YARDI_FUND_TRAN |  2227 | 60129 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  25 |     UNION-ALL                          |                 |       |       |            |          |
|* 26 |      FILTER                            |                 |       |       |            |          |
|  27 |       FAST DUAL                        |                 |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 28 |      FILTER                            |                 |       |       |            |          |
|  29 |       FAST DUAL                        |                 |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 30 |      FILTER                            |                 |       |       |            |          |
|  31 |       FAST DUAL                        |                 |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 32 |      FILTER                            |                 |       |       |            |          |
|  33 |       FAST DUAL                        |                 |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 34 |      FILTER                            |                 |       |       |            |          |
|  35 |       FAST DUAL                        |                 |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 36 |      FILTER                            |                 |       |       |            |          |
|  37 |       FAST DUAL                        |                 |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 38 |      FILTER                            |                 |       |       |            |          |
|  39 |       FAST DUAL                        |                 |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 40 |      FILTER                            |                 |       |       |            |          |
|  41 |       FAST DUAL                        |                 |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   3 - filter( EXISTS ( (SELECT :B1 FROM "SYS"."DUAL" "DUAL" WHERE :B2=:B3) UNION ALL  (SELECT 
              :B4 FROM "SYS"."DUAL" "DUAL" WHERE :B5=:B6) UNION ALL  (SELECT :B7 FROM "SYS"."DUAL" "DUAL" WHERE 
              :B8=:B9) UNION ALL  (SELECT :B10 FROM "SYS"."DUAL" "DUAL" WHERE :B11=:B12) UNION ALL  (SELECT 
              :B13 FROM "SYS"."DUAL" "DUAL" WHERE :B14=:B15) UNION ALL  (SELECT :B16 FROM "SYS"."DUAL" "DUAL" 
              WHERE :B17=:B18) UNION ALL  (SELECT :B19 FROM "SYS"."DUAL" "DUAL" WHERE :B20=:B21) UNION ALL  
              (SELECT :B22 FROM "SYS"."DUAL" "DUAL" WHERE :B23=:B24)))
   4 - access("FT7"."HINVESTMENT"="FT8"."HINVESTOR"(+))
       filter("P"."HMY"<>CASE  WHEN ("FT8"."HINVESTOR"(+) IS NOT NULL) THEN "FT7"."HINVESTMENT" 
              ELSE "FT7"."HINVESTMENT" END )
   5 - storage("FT8"."ICATEGORY"(+)=0)
       filter("FT8"."ICATEGORY"(+)=0 AND SYSDATE@!<=COALESCE("FT8"."DTEND"(+),SYSDATE@!) AND 
              "FT8"."DPERCENT"(+)<>0 AND "FT8"."DTSTART"(+)<=SYSDATE@!)
   6 - access("FT6"."HINVESTMENT"="FT7"."HINVESTOR"(+))
       filter("P"."HMY"<>CASE  WHEN ("FT7"."HINVESTOR"(+) IS NOT NULL) THEN "FT6"."HINVESTMENT" 
              ELSE "FT6"."HINVESTMENT" END )
   7 - storage("FT7"."ICATEGORY"(+)=0)
       filter("FT7"."ICATEGORY"(+)=0 AND SYSDATE@!<=COALESCE("FT7"."DTEND"(+),SYSDATE@!) AND 
              "FT7"."DPERCENT"(+)<>0 AND "FT7"."DTSTART"(+)<=SYSDATE@!)
   8 - access("FT5"."HINVESTMENT"="FT6"."HINVESTOR"(+))
       filter("P"."HMY"<>CASE  WHEN ("FT6"."HINVESTOR"(+) IS NOT NULL) THEN "FT5"."HINVESTMENT" 
              ELSE "FT5"."HINVESTMENT" END )
   9 - storage("FT6"."ICATEGORY"(+)=0)
       filter("FT6"."ICATEGORY"(+)=0 AND SYSDATE@!<=COALESCE("FT6"."DTEND"(+),SYSDATE@!) AND 
              "FT6"."DPERCENT"(+)<>0 AND "FT6"."DTSTART"(+)<=SYSDATE@!)
  10 - access("FT4"."HINVESTMENT"="FT5"."HINVESTOR"(+))
       filter("P"."HMY"<>CASE  WHEN ("FT5"."HINVESTOR"(+) IS NOT NULL) THEN "FT4"."HINVESTMENT" 
              ELSE "FT4"."HINVESTMENT" END )
  11 - storage("FT5"."ICATEGORY"(+)=0)
       filter("FT5"."ICATEGORY"(+)=0 AND SYSDATE@!<=COALESCE("FT5"."DTEND"(+),SYSDATE@!) AND 
              "FT5"."DPERCENT"(+)<>0 AND "FT5"."DTSTART"(+)<=SYSDATE@!)
  12 - access("FT3"."HINVESTMENT"="FT4"."HINVESTOR"(+))
       filter("P"."HMY"<>CASE  WHEN ("FT4"."HINVESTOR"(+) IS NOT NULL) THEN "FT3"."HINVESTMENT" 
              ELSE "FT3"."HINVESTMENT" END )
  13 - storage("FT4"."ICATEGORY"(+)=0)
       filter("FT4"."ICATEGORY"(+)=0 AND SYSDATE@!<=COALESCE("FT4"."DTEND"(+),SYSDATE@!) AND 
              "FT4"."DPERCENT"(+)<>0 AND "FT4"."DTSTART"(+)<=SYSDATE@!)
  14 - access("FT2"."HINVESTMENT"="FT3"."HINVESTOR"(+))
       filter("P"."HMY"<>CASE  WHEN ("FT3"."HINVESTOR"(+) IS NOT NULL) THEN "FT2"."HINVESTMENT" 
              ELSE "FT2"."HINVESTMENT" END )
  15 - storage("FT3"."ICATEGORY"(+)=0)
       filter("FT3"."ICATEGORY"(+)=0 AND SYSDATE@!<=COALESCE("FT3"."DTEND"(+),SYSDATE@!) AND 
              "FT3"."DPERCENT"(+)<>0 AND "FT3"."DTSTART"(+)<=SYSDATE@!)
  16 - access("FT1"."HINVESTMENT"="FT2"."HINVESTOR"(+))
       filter("P"."HMY"<>CASE  WHEN ("FT2"."HINVESTOR"(+) IS NOT NULL) THEN "FT1"."HINVESTMENT" 
              ELSE "FT1"."HINVESTMENT" END )
  17 - storage("FT2"."ICATEGORY"(+)=0)
       filter("FT2"."ICATEGORY"(+)=0 AND SYSDATE@!<=COALESCE("FT2"."DTEND"(+),SYSDATE@!) AND 
              "FT2"."DPERCENT"(+)<>0 AND "FT2"."DTSTART"(+)<=SYSDATE@!)
  18 - access("PX"."HMY"="FT1"."HINVESTOR")
  21 - storage(TRIM(TRAILING ' ' FROM LOWER("PX"."SCODE"))='rdrtinc')
       filter(TRIM(TRAILING ' ' FROM LOWER("PX"."SCODE"))='rdrtinc')
  22 - access("PX"."HMY"="P"."HMY"(+))
  24 - storage("FT1"."ICATEGORY"=0 AND "FT1"."DPERCENT"<>0)
       filter("FT1"."ICATEGORY"=0 AND "FT1"."DPERCENT"<>0 AND 
              NVL("FT1"."DTEND",SYSDATE@!+1)>=SYSDATE@! AND "FT1"."DTSTART"<=SYSDATE@! AND 
              SYS_OP_BLOOM_FILTER(:BF0000,"FT1"."HINVESTOR"))
  26 - filter(:B1=:B2)
  28 - filter(:B1=:B2)
  30 - filter(:B1=:B2)
  32 - filter(:B1=:B2)
  34 - filter(:B1=:B2)
  36 - filter(:B1=:B2)
  38 - filter(:B1=:B2)
  40 - filter(:B1=:B2)
```

Comment: this is the same as the last question. so why did you close it to repost it. Still your query looks wring esoeciall the seöfjoines. You wil have more luck, when post table design and out put and expalin what you tryong to achieve with the query

Comment: because stack overflow suggested to delete it and repost it after some time,